# Android inapp billing subscriptions testing

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscriptions, renewal

Is there any way to test inapp subscriptions renewal without having to wait for the previous purchase to expire? I have searched docs but there seems to be no official way to do it. Have you found any workaround for this, please?

I have create subscriptions with 7 days trial period and I have cancelled the purchase but still I have to wait for 1 whole week to test again...

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Typically we use a test account for subscriptions testing.  
The test account has a very short renewal period.
if you have a monthly subscription, then the test account is renewed every 5 minutes. The yearly one has 30 minutes period.